# How to skip/not run a code in java

Tags: java

```
bSub.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
               if(t1.getText().equals("Name") || t2.getText().equals("Section") || t3.getText().equals("Age")){
                   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please fill in the incomplete fields");
                }
                //If the 'if statement' above is true, these code below will not execute
               t8.setText(t1.getText() + " of " + t2.getText() + " -- " + t3.getText() + " years old");
               t9.setText(t1.getText() + " of " + t2.getText() + " -- " + t3.getText() + " years old");
               t10.setText(t1.getText() + " of " + t2.getText() + " -- " + t3.getText() + " years old");
               t11.setText(t1.getText() + " of " + t2.getText() + " -- " + t3.getText() + " years old");
               t12.setText(t1.getText() + " of " + t2.getText() + " -- " + t3.getText() + " years old");
            }
        });
```

Is it possible to tell the compiler to skip a code if the 'If Statement' is true?

Comment: use `else { }` statement

Comment: insert the else statement in order to choose when to execute which block

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Place the other code in an `else`:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
           if(t1.getText().equals("Name") || t2.getText().equals("Section") || t3.getText().equals("Age")){
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please fill in the incomplete fields");
            } else {
              //If the 'if statement' above is true, these code below will not execute
               t8.setText(t1.getText() + " of " + t2.getText() + " -- " + t3.getText() + " years old");
               t9.setText(t1.getText() + " of " + t2.getText() + " -- " + t3.getText() + " years old");
               t10.setText(t1.getText() + " of " + t2.getText() + " -- " + t3.getText() + " years old");
               t11.setText(t1.getText() + " of " + t2.getText() + " -- " + t3.getText() + " years old");
               t12.setText(t1.getText() + " of " + t2.getText() + " -- " + t3.getText() + " years old");
           }

        }
```

Comment: Why haven't I thought of that, haha. Thank you so much for helping me with my project :)

Answer (score 1):

You may skip by `return` keyword:

```
if(t1.getText().equals("Name") || t2.getText().equals("Section") || t3.getText().equals("Age")){
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please fill in the incomplete fields");
      return;
}
```

Comment: Though adding a return in that fashion is poor "programming style" since it tends to make the code less "obvious" and introduce bugs.